# Is there a way to create an alias to a Redshift table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the requirement to change several table names to adjust to a convention (it's just in Dev). However, there are several consumers already using those tables (directly, then again it's just Dev and it will not be kept that way). Is there a way to change the name and keep the old one as an alias, for a transition period? I have browsed Redshift documentation but I haven't found anything like that. 
Thank you!

Comment: I thought of creating a temporary View. I don't know if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `CREATE VIEW` is the closest thing to an *alias*.

It also gives you the ability to present a subset of columns and even differently-named columns, which can be handy when migrating to a new schema.